# Why does my presentedViewController's view with 80% alpha revert to opaque?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to present a partially transparent UIViewController; but the view immediately snaps to opaque...after briefly shows some transparency.

Here's the IB Attribute Inspector:

[image]

I present this particular UIViewController via:

```
self.presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But once the UIViewController is displayed, it reverts to opaque.

I tried to force the 80% without success:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let myColor = self.view.backgroundColor
    let semi = myColor!.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)
    self.view.backgroundColor = semi
}
```

How can I force it to remain 80% opaque?

Comment: write code in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I can do it in objective c using UIView. there is no problem, write code in viewDidLoad

Comment: ahh getting same problem while set alpha to self.view.backgroound

Comment: This is obviously a *** BUG ***.  So I filed a bug report:#19192703